# How to exclude "[" character in RegEx

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a string of mail headers and their values. Unfortunately it comes as a string, and I want to exclude some patterns that are not really mail headers.

Below is what I have:

```
Return-Path: Received: from out.ipsmtp4nec.opaltelecom.net (out.ipsmtp4nec.opaltelecom.net [62.24.202.76]) by smartermail.divtech.co.za with SMTP; Mon, 6 Jul 2015 12:59:14 +0200 X-SMTPAUTH: sailor26@tiscali.co.uk X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Filtered: true X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result: A2DSrwBOXppVPOPoVl0aAUErgmdUYIMfp3gMBgGBA4IZK4VrAYJ3V4ckhW8EKYEFTQEBAQEBAQcBAQEBQAE/HwEBIAECAoNdAQIMGzMuCgYDAQIPHw4COwoCCAEGCQESCAmICAMWCZFaoGKWHYYdhS6CTR6FCi+BFAWFXAqOLQIBhGGFJ4FfkTmHHYFvAQEIAQEBAQEBgiI+MYJLAQEB X-IPAS-Result: A2DSrwBOXppVPOPoVl0aAUErgmdUYIMfp3gMBgGBA4IZK4VrAYJ3V4ckhW8EKYEFTQEBAQEBAQcBAQEBQAE/HwEBIAECAoNdAQIMGzMuCgYDAQIPHw4COwoCCAEGCQESCAmICAMWCZFaoGKWHYYdhS6CTR6FCi+BFAWFXAqOLQIBhGGFJ4FfkTmHHYFvAQEIAQEBAQEBgiI+MYJLAQEB X-Header: TalkTalk X-IronPort-AV: E=Sophos;i=""5.15,414,1432594800""; d=""scan'208,217"";a=""693647776"" Received: from 93-86-232-227.dynamic.isp.telekom.rs (HELO smtp.tiscali.co.uk) ([93.86.232.227]) by out.ipsmtp4nec.opaltelecom.net with ESMTP; 06 Jul 2015 11:59:04 +0100 Message-ID: From: "jonjon.bracq" To: "Webtickets" , "Webtickets Highlights" , "RYA" , "www jobonyachts com ADMIN" , "RYA InBrief" , "RYA InBrief" , "Webtickets Highlights" , "Webtickets Regional Highlights" , "RYA InBrief" Subject:
=?ISO-8859-1?Q?FW=3AFrom=3Ajonjon.bracq=40yahoo.com?= Date: Thu, 26 Jun 2015 11:59:43 +0000 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_00BE_8320AA74.4FC1860E" X-Priority: 3 X-MSMail-Priority: Normal Importance: Normal X-Mailer: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 16.4.3522.110 X-MIMEOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V16.4.3522.110 X-SmarterMail-Spam: SPF_Pass, RHSBL, UCEProtect Level 1, Bayesian Filtering, ISpamAssassin 0 [raw: 0], DK_None, DKIM_None, Custom Rules [] X-SmarterMail-TotalSpamWeight: 12
```

I want to match all Headers (words followed by ":") excluding raw: which is inside the [] brackets. This is because raw: is part of the value of `X-SmarterMail-Spam` header (towards the end of the list). I don't want to remove "raw:" manually as there might be other such values in the future.

The expression `/(\D[a-z\-]*)(\:)+/ig` includes "raw:".

**Note:** I included `\D` so that I can exclude time (`11:59:43`) too, but I can't seem to be able to exclude "raw:". Please help.

Comment: How does the title of your question relate to your question? I don't see anything about `[` characters in the question.

Comment: ColdFusion doesn't use Java regex, as far as I can gather from the documentation. At least, Java doesn't support `[[:punct:]]` (it uses `\p{Punct}` instead).

Comment: You have to use the rules a reader would use to parse headers. No more, no less. Anything else is a waste of time.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, if you check the header string I have you will see that there is [raw: 0]

Comment: @SollyM: *The valid headers are not inside any brackets.*  That is why you need to match them out. What about my approach? Here is an update: [`\[[^\]]*\]|([a-z-]+):`](https://regex101.com/r/vV4wT8/2).

Comment: @stribizhev, unfortunately the expression you have works online but not with ColdFusion. When extracting the `X-SmarterMail-Spam` header, it cuts the value just before `raw:` but includes the `[`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw:` is a syntactically valid header name, so you'll have to add context in order to single it out. As its occurrence seems to be a rare exception, I'd suggest not to cater for it in the match but to filter it in subsequent processing.

However, if you want to keep it in the regexp, rule out the opening bracket and make sure that the complete header string is matched. Beware of using `\D` to start the regexp as this is way too loose a condition (eg. it would also also match the opening bracket ...):

```
([^\[a-z_0-9\-]|^)([a-z_\-][a-z0-9_\-]*:)/ig
```

Regex checked at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/fS2zB3/3) against your sample input.

Comment: if you look at the header you will notice that raw: is inside the [] brackets as part of the value for `X-SmarterMail-Spam:` header. The valid headers are not inside any brackets.

Comment: That's missing a match at the beginning of the string (`Return-Path:`). It should work with a minor adjustment: `([^\[a-z_0-9\-]|^)([a-z_\-][a-z0-9_\-]*:)`

Comment: Your response is the same as the direction I took but needed to give you credit anyway.

Comment: @CarstenHagemann Thx for spotting this issue, I#ve adjusted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my final code. I know there are some lines that needed to be removed, but I left them there because they don't add too much overhead on the execution.

```
<cffunction name="GetHeader" output="yes" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="header" required="yes" type="string">
    <cfargument name="property" required="yes" type="string">

    <cfset return = "">

    <cfset propFinderPos = REFind(property & ":",header) >

    <cfif propFinderPos GT 0>
        <cfset propValueStart = propFinderPos + LEN(property) + 1 >

        <cfset propNextPos = REFind("(\D[A-Za-z\-]*)(\:)",header,propValueStart,"TRUE") >

        <cfif propNextPos.pos[1] GT 0 >
            <!--- test to see if there is no "[" --->
            <cfif Mid(header,propNextPos.pos[1],1) EQ "[">
                <cfset propNextPos = REFind("(\D[A-Za-z\-]*)(\:)",header,propNextPos.pos[1]+propNextPos.len[1],"TRUE") >
           </cfif>

            <cfset propValueEnd = propNextPos.pos[1] >
        <cfelse>
            <cfset propValueEnd = LEN(header) >
        </cfif>      
        <cfset header2 = Mid(header,1,propValueEnd)>
        <cfset return = Mid(header2, propValueStart, propValueEnd)>
   <cfelse>
    <cfset return = "~not found~" >
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn return >

</cffunction>


<cfoutput>
    X-SmarterMail-Spam = #GetHeader(header,"X-SmarterMail-Spam")#
</cfoutput>
```

returns `X-SmarterMail-Spam = SPF_Pass, RHSBL, UCEProtect Level 1, Bayesian Filtering, ISpamAssassin 0 [raw: 0], DK_None, DKIM_None, Custom Rules []`

Comment: (Edit) Do not forget to localize any function local variables ie `var/local` scope. Though you might want to avoid using keywords like "return" as variable names.  Also, keep in mind there can be multiple instances of certain headers. As an aside, if the actual string of mail headers contains new line characters, you could probably use the [InternetHeaders](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetHeaders.html) class to do the parsing, instead of a homespun regex. It is not exactly what you need, but makes extraction of header "name/value" pairs a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a generic solution for parsing email headers, but just to throw out another possibility... if your header string is delimited by *new lines*, like in a typical email:

```
...
X-Priority: 3 
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal Importance: Normal 
X-SmarterMail-Spam: SPF_Pass, RHSBL, UCEProtect Level 1, Bayesian Filtering, ISpamAssassin 0 [raw: 0], DK_None, DKIM_None, Custom Rules [] 
...
```

You could use the core [javax.mail.internet.InternetHeaders](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetHeaders.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-) class to do the parsing. Unlike your current regex, this class is specifically designed to parse RFC822 headers (ie email headers). To use it, create an InputStream from your delimited string and load it into the headers object:

```
// create stream from delimited string
stream = createObject("java", "java.io.StringBufferInputStream").init( yourString );
// load stream and extract all headers
mimeHeaders = createObject("java", "javax.mail.internet.InternetHeaders");
mimeHeaders.load( stream );
```

Once the string is loaded, you can grab whatever headers you need from the instance. For example, to retrieve the "X-SmarterMail-Spam" header:

```
headers = mimeHeaders.getHeader("X-SmarterMail-Spam");
if (!isNull(headers)) {
    writeDump(headers);
}
```

***NB:*** There can be multiple occurrences of some headers, so this method returns an array, or null if the header does not exist.

Comment: Unfortunately the `cfpop`'s `header` property returns a `space delimited` string. Otherwise it found have been easier.

Comment: Silly cfpop. You should not have to resort to string parsing. Especially as some headers can occur multiple times.  Anyway, agreed it will not work in your case, but it is good generic parsing option for properly delimited headers (too long for comments).